# How to accumulate results in a Seq for later processing in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to process each row in a Spark dataframe, and convert this to another data frame. Essentially, I have a frame A which contains a column ("id") and another column which is array of sentences. I'd like to convert this to another dataframe with each sentence uniquely identified with a "docID:count" identifier string. My code is:

```
var sentencesCollection:Seq[SentenceIdentifier] = Seq()
tokenized.foreach(row => {
    val docID = row.getAs[String]("id")
    val sentences = row.getAs[Seq[String]]("sentences")
    var count:Integer = 0
    for (elem <- sentences) {
        val sentenceID:String = docID + ":" + count
        count = count + 1

        val si = SentenceIdentifier(sentenceID, elem)
        sentencesCollection = sentencesCollection :+ si
     }

})

println(sentencesCollection.length)
```

However, the println statement prints "0".

Any idea how I can have sentencesCollection be the sequence that I can further process downstream ? (Possibly thought a .toDF() call).

Comment: That wont work, because the `foreach` is executed by the **Executors** _(probably in another machine in another jvm)_ while your `Seq` only lives in the **Driver**. This has bee asked before uncountable amount of times. If you want to have a local copy of your data, use `collect`. - However, since what you want to do is create a new `DataFrame`, create a local collection would be a waste of memory and a performance bottle neck. There are a lot of methods to create a new `DataFrame` from another, like select, filter or map _(on `Dataset`)_. I think you should read more about how **Spark** works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111404/luis-miguel-mej%C3%ADa-su%C3%A1rez) explained very well in a comment, any function passed as the argument of `DataFrame.foreach` will be executed on one or more executor machine, not on the driver running this code, therefore any change to mutable state will be lost (it will be performed on the executors and thrown away).

When working with DataFrames, you should always think in terms of **transforming** one DF to another, using nothing but Spark's APIs to do so. These transformations are "instructions" for Spark, to be executed by it distributedly.

In this case, your requirement can be achieved with this in mind. You want to:

- **Explode** the records, meaning turn every record containing an array to multiple records each with one element from the array
- Keep track of the exploded element's **position** in the array
- **Concat** that position to the existing value of the "id" column with ":" as separator

Each one of these actions can be achieved through one of Spark's **functions** meant to be executed on DataFrame columns. Here's how the solution looks like:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

// Sample data
val tokenized = Seq(
  (1, Array("Hi there", "Hello there")),
  (2, Array("Bye now")),
  (3, Array("Thank you", "Thanks", "Many thanks"))
).toDF("id", "sentences")

val result = tokenized
   // we'll use posexplode function which creates "pos" and "col" columns
  .select($"id", posexplode($"sentences")) 
   // we'll create a new docID column using concat function, and rename "col"
  .select(concat($"id", lit(":"), $"pos") as "docID", $"col" as "sentence")

result.show()
// +-----+-----------+
// |docID|   sentence|
// +-----+-----------+
// |  1:0|   Hi there|
// |  1:1|Hello there|
// |  2:0|    Bye now|
// |  3:0|  Thank you|
// |  3:1|     Thanks|
// |  3:2|Many thanks|
// +-----+-----------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked beautifully. I will definitely understand basics of Spark more as well.